# Automatic tracking update on Amazon - Does a new carrier carrier push or Amazon has to setup the carrier and configure a pull

Tags: amazon-selling-partner-api, amazonsellercentral

Seller wants to use a Other carrier to handle seller fulfilled orders. **That is, a carrier that is not USPS, UPS, FedEx.**

We can mark the orders as shipped and push the tracking information using SP-API

**POST /orders/v0/orders/{orderId}/shipment**

However as this is not a Amazon listed carrier the tracking information is not automatically updated by Amazon. On the buyers side the order **shows up as running late even after it is delivered by the courier**.

How can the carrier or seller push the delivery status for the order?  Is there a operation in SP-API to update the tracking status to delivered ? I was unable to see a way in the Seller Central to achieve this even using the UI.

How does Amazon automatically update the status of order for tracking with carriers like USPS, UPS, FedEx ? Do they pull the tracking information from these carriers or do the carriers somehow push status to Amazon ?

We want to not update the status and complete the order and prevent the buyer from logging a refund request.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you able to figure this out?